# Failed to mount a NAS with fstab on Alpine

Tags: networking, mount, fstab

I installed Alpine linux on my Raspberry Pi and I have some troubles to mount a network disk.

I have this line in my `/etc/fstab` file on my RPi and on another computer (running Archlinux)

```
# /etc/fstab
//192.168.1.10/GoFlex\040Home\040Public  /media/nas  cifs  credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=100,uid=1000  0  0
```

When I do `mount -a`, it work on my computer and it give me this on my RPi:

```
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
mount: mounting //192.168.1.10/GoFlex\040Home\040Public on /media/nas failed: No such device or address
```

I can mount with the following command though:

```
mount -t cifs "//192.168.1.10/GoFlex Home Public" /media/nas -o credentials=/root/.smbcredentials
```

So it seems that the \040 sequence is not replaced by the space character.

How can I make my fstab working ?

Comment: So what is your question? Why not just use one of the working alternatives?

Comment: Because I want to mount my NAS on start.
I want to make my fstab working.

Comment: The \040 syntax for spaces is indeed correct, so I'd love if some of the close voters explained how this is **not** RPi-specific.